# Swift: How to update row

Tags: ios

In the code below is the code that I used to save the data in JSON whenever any change is made but the problem is that I want to save only that field that is edited and not all fields. 
ps: I have use Eureka Forms.

Comment: What disadvantages are there if you save all fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to store a set of rows that are edited.

```
var editedRowTags: Set<String>()
```

In the `onChange` callback of each row, add the row's tag into the set:

```
editedRowTags.insert(row.tag!)
```

In the save button's `IBAction`, loop through the set and get the rows using the tags, then `addRequest` the values.

```
for tag in editedRowTags {
    let row = form.rowBy(tag: tag)
    requestsArray.addRequest(withValue: row.baseValue!, forFieldName: tag)
}
```

Comment: @Kdr Yeah that's right. `self` is captured so you have to write it explicitly. Also, add `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` if you want to avoid retain cycles.

Comment: @Kdr I have added `[weak self]` using your link.